# git archive to remote fails with the error `git-upload-archive: command not found`

Tags: git

I've tried to export my branch to remote server which doesn't have git installed with the following:
`git archive --format=tar --remote=ssh://user@env.com/path/to/folder dev | tar -xf -`
However, I got the following error:

```
bash: git-upload-archive: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

What could be the reason for the failure?
If I try the archive to local repository everything works fine:
`git archive master | tar -x -C /path/to/local/folder`

Comment: If the remote server "doesn't have git installed", why are you trying to run `git` commands on it? I think that's a reasonable "reason for the failure"...

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the `archive` command. It seems now that it's more like import rather than export.